# Get exception when I try to raise an event

Tags: c#, events, enums, delegates

I got an enum:

```
public enum sprog{
   dansk,
   svensk,
   norsk
}
```

In a method I would raise an event and use the enum to carry information:

```
public delegate void BrugerSprogChanged(Object sender, Sprog sprog);
class clazz
{
    public event BrugerSprogChanged brugerSprogChanced;
    public clazz(){}

    private void comboBoxDokumentSprog_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Sprog sprog = FindSprog((string)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem);
        dokumentSprogChanged(this, sprog); // <- here we have the problem
    }
}
```

When the code shall raise the event I get an exception when dokumentSprogChanged(this, sprg) is called:

*"NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

*Object reference not set to an instance of an object"*

"this" and "sprog" are not null.

Any suggestions?

The easy way is to drop the unem and use an integer/string instead, but then I end up with some ugly code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: *`this` and `sprog` are not null* What about `dokumentSprogChanged` ? I believe `brugerSprogChanced` event is never subscribed.

Comment: In particular, think of `dokumentSprogChanged(this, sprog);` as being translated to `dokumentSprogChanged.Invoke(this, sprog);` and it may be more obvious why you're getting the exception.

Comment: dokumentSprogChanged.Invoke(this, sprog); throws the same exception

Comment: Sriram was right. When I add an subscriber the problem disappears. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally to call an event you have to check if it's handler is not null:

```
var handler = dokumentSprogChanged; // take a local reference

if (handler != null)
{
    dokumentSprogChanged(this, sprog);
}
```

This way you can raise it safely.

**EDIT**

You need to register the event like this:

```
public event BrugerSprogChanged brugerSprogChanced;

....
brugerSprogChanced += class_brugerSprogChanced;
....

void class_brugerSprogChanced(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // handle there
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem now is that the handler is null. I use another event: public delegate void ValgteSprogChanged(bool da, bool fo); which work without problems. Maybe it's illigal to use an enum in a delegate/event

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class clazz
{
    public event BrugerSprogChanged brugerSprogChanced;
    public clazz(){}

    private void comboBoxDokumentSprog_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Sprog sprog = FindSprog((string)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem);
        if (dokumentSprogChanged != null)
        {
            dokumentSprogChanged(this, sprog); // <- here we have the problem
        }
    }
}
```